# Matching multiple parts in an elixir binary for parsing HTTP/2.0 frames

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, elixir, binary-data

I have discovered a quick way to match a frame from a binary.
The length matches as an integer and part c (the payload) has as many octets as declared in the length field. (First three octets)

```
<<length::24, b::48, c::binary-size(length)>> <> rest = buffer
```

The problem is to get at my frame I need to recombine the parts.

```
frame = <<length::24, b::48, c::binary>>
```

Is there anyway to assign the frame variable in the original match. Something like the following. *Though this precise version does not work*

```
(frame = <<length::24, _::48, _::binary-size(length)>>) <> rest = buffer
```

Edit, or some syntax like the following would also make sense

```
<< frame = <<length::24, _::48, _::binary-size(length)>>, rest::binary>>
```

Comment: You probably already know this, but to prevent having to recreate the binary, you can use `:binary.part(buffer, 0, 3 + 6 + length)`. `:binary.part/3` will create a sub binary from the original `buffer` instead of allocating a new binary.

Comment: I did not know that sounds helpful, still a two step process to get the binary i want but probaly pretty quick

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it’s impossible exactly this way, but you might declare a handy helper to avoid repetitive typing:

```
def matcher(buffer)
  with <<length::24, b::48, c::binary-size(length), rest::binary>> <- buffer do 
    {:ok, <<length::24, b::48, c::binary-size(length)>>, rest}
  else
    other -> {:error, other}
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```
{:ok, frame, rest} = matcher(buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks, not wanting to sound ungrateful, but I had got this far :-). I was wondering if one line was possible because it might be more performant. No creation and concatenation of the temporary binaries

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what part of the header that `b::48` signifies.

But anyway, performance wise it's important to consider a couple of things.

1. You're not being performant by returning a frame binary. If you have parsed the frame and know it is complete then return it as a `etf` representation. Don't reparse it again.
2. One line isn't necessarily more performant. It's all about combining and extracting binary parts in certain ways.
3. Pattern Matching in function definitions is also very performant, do it as much as possible for different code paths.

I don't know how performant `<>` really is. I think it is just shorthand, but it's probably performant enough even if it different.

This bit of code should create and link binary parts and shouldn't create any new binaries. Therefore it is actually quite performant.

```erlang
<<length::24, b::48, c::binary-size(length), rest::binary>> = buffer
frame = <<length::24, b::48, c::binary>>
```

If you want to see how I handled this kind of data then take a look at [`WebSockex.Frame`](https://github.com/Azolo/websockex/blob/32283a8ce319ed50fe7ccd28ffde2908ca78eeb7/lib/websockex/frame.ex).

Comment: Are you sure `frame = <<length::24, b::48, c::binary>>` will share the original binary? I just created a 1 megabyte buffer containing a single frame and created a list of 100 `<<length::24, b::48, c::binary>>` and my memory usage went up by 100MB. On the other hand, if I create a list of 100 `frame = :binary.part(buffer, 0, 9999999)`, my memory usage remains about the same.

Comment: Yes, but it is a compile time optimization. See **Match Context** on the [Erlang Binary Handling](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html) page.